# Why doesn't [link description](URL) work for me in the comments?

Tags: support, comment, markdown, hyperlinks

I've posted a comment here:
[The $55$-th IMO, problem $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107746/the-55-th-imo-problem-1#comment2258751_1107746)

And it doesn't display the format

> [link description](link URL)

properly. What is wrong?

Comment: I have fixed the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I look at the specific comment [you linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107746/the-55-th-imo-problem-1#comment2258751_1107746), I think that the only problems is that you did not include `http://` at the beginning of the link.

You wrote this:
`[ArtOfProblemSolving forum](www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3542095&sid=61650444d5d??5e56fb5c71a50982e4912#p3542095)`
which does not work: 
ArtOfProblemSolving forum.

If you write this:
`[ArtOfProblemSolving forum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3542095&sid=61650444d5d??5e56fb5c71a50982e4912#p3542095)`
it should work: [ArtOfProblemSolving forum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3542095&sid=61650444d5d??5e56fb5c71a50982e4912#p3542095).

See the comments below this post where I tested it.

Comment: Here is a comment containing the first possibility (without http): [ArtOfProblemSolving forum](www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3542095&sid=61650444d5d??5e56fb5c71a50982e4912#p3542095)

Comment: Here is a comment containing the second possibility (with http): [ArtOfProblemSolving forum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3542095&sid=61650444d5d??5e56fb5c71a50982e4912#p3542095)